# XSLT - I have a header value mapped and want to map a line value below

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I want TaxTotal on the InvoiceLine to be created depending on a header value. Then I want a line value (LIT_VatExcludedAmount) to be mapped to the correct line (in TaxableAmount).

I only get it working to map the value of the first line to each line in the target. Or to have all values of the source on each line. So, for 3 lines, 3 results in each line.

Source:

```
<Documents>
    <Document>
        <Invoice>
            <Fields>
                <Field Type="BTWverlegd" TextDetail="AE">Ja</Field>
            </Fields>
            <Tables>
                <Table>
                    <TableRow>
                        <Field Name="Li_Omschrijving" Type="LIT_ArticleName" PageNumber="1" Position="223,1528,377,1560">Artikel 1</Field>
                        <Field Name="Li_Aantal" Type="LIT_DeliveredQuantity" PageNumber="1" Position="1509,1530,1585,1566">3.00</Field>
                        <Field Name="Li_EenheidsPrijs" Type="LIT_UnitPriceAmount" PageNumber="1" Position="1832,1530,1908,1566">2.25</Field>
                        <Field Name="Li_NettoBedrag" Type="LIT_VatExcludedAmount" PageNumber="1" Position="2154,1530,2230,1566">6.75</Field>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow>
                        <Field Name="Li_Omschrijving" Type="LIT_ArticleName" PageNumber="1" Position="223,1589,377,1621">Artikel 2</Field>
                        <Field Name="Li_Aantal" Type="LIT_DeliveredQuantity" PageNumber="1" Position="1509,1591,1585,1627">5.00</Field>
                        <Field Name="Li_EenheidsPrijs" Type="LIT_UnitPriceAmount" PageNumber="1" Position="1809,1591,1909,1627">28.00</Field>
                        <Field Name="Li_NettoBedrag" Type="LIT_VatExcludedAmount" PageNumber="1" Position="2109,1591,2229,1627">140.00</Field>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow>
                        <Field Name="Li_Omschrijving" Type="LIT_ArticleName" PageNumber="1" Position="223,1649,376,1681">Artikel 3</Field>
                        <Field Name="Li_Aantal" Type="LIT_DeliveredQuantity" PageNumber="1" Position="1509,1651,1585,1687">7.00</Field>
                        <Field Name="Li_EenheidsPrijs" Type="LIT_UnitPriceAmount" PageNumber="1" Position="1810,1651,1910,1687">15.50</Field>
                        <Field Name="Li_NettoBedrag" Type="LIT_VatExcludedAmount" PageNumber="1" Position="2109,1651,2229,1687">108.50</Field>
                    </TableRow>
                </Table>
            </Tables>   
        </Invoice>      
    </Document>
</Documents>
```

XSLT code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Documents/Document/Invoice/Tables/Table/TableRow">
    <cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
            <xsl:value-of select="Field[@Type='LIT_DeliveredQuantity']"/>
        </cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
    <xsl:for-each select="../../../Fields/Field[@Type='BTWverlegd' and @TextDetail='AE']">
            <cac:TaxTotal>
                <cac:TaxSubtotal>
                    <cbc:TaxableAmount>
                        <xsl:for-each select="/Documents/Document/Invoice/Tables/Table/TableRow">
                            <xsl:value-of select="/Documents/Document/Invoice/Tables/Table/TableRow/Field[@Type='LIT_VatExcludedAmount']"/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </cbc:TaxableAmount>
                </cac:TaxSubtotal>
            </cac:TaxTotal>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </cac:InvoiceLine>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I expect something like below, where each line has the correct TaxableAmount.
I already tried select="Field[@Type='LIT_VatExcludedAmount']", but then I only get an empty tag.

```
<Invoice>
    <cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cbc:InvoicedQuantity>3.00</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
        <cac:TaxTotal>
            <cac:TaxSubtotal>
                <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="EUR">6.75</cbc:TaxableAmount>
            </cac:TaxSubtotal>
        </cac:TaxTotal>
    </cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cac:TaxTotal>
            <cbc:InvoicedQuantity>5.00</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
            <cac:TaxSubtotal>
                <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="EUR">140.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
            </cac:TaxSubtotal>
        </cac:TaxTotal>
    </cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cbc:ID/>
        <cbc:InvoicedQuantity>7.00</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
        <cac:TaxTotal>
            <cac:TaxSubtotal>
                <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="EUR">108.50</cbc:TaxableAmount>
            </cac:TaxSubtotal>
        </cac:TaxTotal>
    </cac:InvoiceLine>
</Invoice>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to change the inner `xsl:for-each` to an `xsl:if`, otherwise you will position yourself on a different node, and lose what `tableRow` you were positioned on

```
 <xsl:if test="../../../Fields/Field[@Type='BTWverlegd' and @TextDetail='AE']">
```

Also, within your inner `xsl:for-each` you have this `xsl:value-of` statement

```
<xsl:value-of select="/Documents/Document/....
```

By starting the expression with `/` you are ignoring what node you have currently selected, and searching the whole document instead.

You don't really need an `xsl:for-each` here at all anyway. Just this will do...

```
<xsl:value-of select="Field[@Type='LIT_VatExcludedAmount']"/>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:cac="cac"
    xmlns:cbc="cbc"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="Documents/Document/Invoice/Tables/Table/TableRow">
        <cac:InvoiceLine>
            <cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
                <xsl:value-of select="Field[@Type='LIT_DeliveredQuantity']"/>
            </cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
            <xsl:if test="../../../Fields/Field[@Type='BTWverlegd' and @TextDetail='AE']">
                <cac:TaxTotal>
                    <cac:TaxSubtotal>
                        <cbc:TaxableAmount>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Field[@Type='LIT_VatExcludedAmount']"/>
                        </cbc:TaxableAmount>
                    </cac:TaxSubtotal>
                </cac:TaxTotal>
            </xsl:if>
        </cac:InvoiceLine>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you! I have been puzzling for a whiele, but the xsl:if solved it!